# Composite Primary keys and Foreign key constraint error

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints, composite

I have an SQL table defined as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [TestComposite] (  
    ID int,  
    SiteUrl nvarchar(255),  
    Name nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,  
    ParentID int NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, SiteUrl)  
);
```

Items and folders are stored inside the same table, if an item is inside a folder, the ParentID column is the ID of the folder.
And I would like to be able to delete CASCADE items/folders when I delete a folder.

An example may be more explicit:

```
INSERT INTO [TestComposite] VALUES (1, 'site1', 'Item1', NULL)
INSERT INTO [TestComposite] VALUES (2, 'site1', 'Item2', NULL)
INSERT INTO [TestComposite] VALUES (3, 'site1', 'Folder1', NULL)
INSERT INTO [TestComposite] VALUES (4, 'site1', 'Folder1.Item1', 3)
INSERT INTO [TestComposite] VALUES (5, 'site1', 'Folder1.Item2', 3)
INSERT INTO [TestComposite] VALUES (6, 'site1', 'Folder1.Folder1', 3)
INSERT INTO [TestComposite] VALUES (7, 'site1', 'Folder1.Folder1.Item1', 6)
etc...
```

So if I delete the item 3 (a folder), I want the items/folders 4, 5, 6 and 7 to be deleted too.

I tried to add a constraint similar to:

```
ALTER TABLE [TestComposite] 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_parentid 
FOREIGN KEY (ParentID, SiteUrl) 
REFERENCES [TestComposite] (ID, SiteUrl) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But it gives me this error:
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'fk_parentid' on table 'TestComposite' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I also tried to add a second SiteUrl column named ParentSiteUrl, in case the problem was that a column couln't be part of the same FK/PK, but I have the same error message.

Am i doing something wrong?

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an `ON DELETE NO ACTION` constraint and use this to delete all records and their children:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  id, SiteURL
        FROM    TestComposite
        WHERE   id = 3
                AND SiteURL = 'site1'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  tc.id, tc.SiteURL
        FROM    q
        JOIN    TestComposite tc
        ON      tc.ParentID = q.Id
                AND tc.SiteURL = q.SiteURL
        )
DELETE
FROM    TestComposite
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  id, SiteURL
        INTERSECT
        SELECT  *
        FROM    q
        )
```

Comment: I may be wrong as I haven't tested it yet, but I don't think it would delete the item 7 in my case, as it is at another level of the hierarchy ?!

Comment: `@OmaR`: yes it will delete `7` as well. It's a recursive `CTE`.

Comment: Thank you, it works great. I didn't know about recursive CTE. And it seems like it works on both SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Can you explain the last WHERE?  Is it the same as `WHERE id IN
(SELECT  id FROM q)`?

Comment: @Henry: it would be the same as `WHERE (id, siteUrl) IN (SELECT id, siteUrl FROM q)` if SQL Server supported it.

Comment: @Henry: no it does not, not with tuple syntax (multiple columns in the inner `SELECT`)

Comment: @Quassnoi oh right, it worked 'cause I dumb it down to only use `id` for my prototype.  Can you please explain what is the inner `INTERSECT` doing?

Comment: @Henry: `EXISTS (SELECT x INTERSECT SELECT y)` is the same as `x = y` except that it matches null values on both sides too (unlike `=`) and works on tuples. The standard has a special clause for this, `IS DISTINCT FROM`, but it's not supported by SQL Server either. So the inner query is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM q WHERE (q.id = testComposite.id OR (q.id IS NULL AND testComposite.id IS NULL)) AND (q.siteUrl = testComposite.siteUrl OR (q.siteUrl IS NULL AND testComposite.siteUrl IS NULL))`. My construct seems more legible to me, that's why I'm using it instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server 2008, use from [HierarchyID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx) type for this work.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do can be achieved by adding a new column called ParentId, and then declare it as foreign key with primary key.
That way the problem will be solved and you can still do everything you want

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you would want me to do?!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create possibility of recursive cascade - when every deleted by cascade can create any number of subsequent deletes. MS SQL doesn't support it. Try to delete them in your code manually. BTW i don't recommend cascade deletes.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321843

Comment: As I told Ardman, if I don't have a composite primary key, say only ID, I would be able to create a recursive Foreign Key without problem.
CREATE TABLE myTable ( ID int PRIMARY KEY, Name nvarchar(max), ParentID int); 
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT fk_parentID FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES myTable(ID) ON CASCADE DELETE;
No ?!

Comment: no you can't! i just tried. it is not about composite key or not, it is about you can create a recursion on cascade and sql server doesn't want to do it itself

Comment: That's weird, I would swear I have already made that... I will test it again :)